# JQuery - Attach (duplicate, clone) li and put it above a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, duplicates, html-lists

Is it possible to clone a specific < li> and put it above an other specific < li>?

Any clue would help me..?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Pseudo Javascript (JQuery)

```
$('#main ul li:eq(3)').duplicateAndPutAbove('#main ul li:eq(2)');
```

HTML Result

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 3</li> <!-- Item 3 was duplicated (or cloned) and then putted ABOVE Item 2 -->
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were *really* close, you wanted [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) (and remember that `eq` is zero-based):

```
$('#main ul li:eq(2)').clone().insertBefore('#main ul li:eq(1)');
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iheze5)

Comment: @Chowder - is appendTo the correct function to use if you're putting it under the li?

Comment: @jmort253: No, `insertBefore` -- I caught it immediately after pressing the button and fixed it (after a brief memory lapse -- insufficient coffee -- that made me write `before`). Doh!

Comment: @jmort: "C**r**owder". ;-) What, you from New England?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#main ul li:eq(3)').clone().insertBefore('#main ul li:eq(2)');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8LpuN/

Answer (score 3):

```
  var elem = $('li').contains('3').clone();  // make a copy
  $('li').contains('Item 3').before(elem);   // insert before the cloned element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main ul li:eq(3)').clone().insertBefore('#main ul li:eq(2)');
```